# Problema al hacer un push en GIT (error 403)

Tags: git, push

Tengo que hacer un push de mi rama en para el repositorio. He hecho un "add" y un "commit" sin ningún problema. La consola me devuelve:

```
# git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
# nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

El problema viene cuando intento hacer un push de la rama:

```
# git push origin git@github.com:Letram/Carlos-Martel-Lamas.git
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing
https://github.com/Letram/Carlos-Martel-Lamas.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

¿A qué se puede deber?

Como dato adicional, para iniciar el repositorio cloné el mismo e hice un par de cambios. Me parece raro que no me pida usuario ni contraseña cuando quiero hacer un push.

Comment: No existe la sintaxis `git push origin <URL de Origin>`, debiera ser `git push origin master`. Y si tienes bien asociadas las ramas, simplemente `git push`. Revisa el archivo `.git/config` a ver cuál es la url de tu remoto. Pareciera ser que el remoto declarado es con `https`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya revisé el fichero `.git/config` y, en efecto, es como comentas. En tal caso, aún siendo así (el clone sí que lo hice vía HTTPS), me sigue comentando que no puedo llevar a cabo el pusheo por el mismo error. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Dices que al hacer `git push` o `git push origin master` te da el mismo error? ¿puedes copiar el contenido de tu `.git/config` a la pregunta?

Comment: Puedes agregar el resultado de:  git remote -v